# Sidekiq - Scheduling emails using a Datetime object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a Todo list app in Rails 4 to learn more about running background jobs and cron. Currently I use Sidekiq to send task confirmation mails asynchronously `EmailWorker.perform_in(5.minutes, @todo.id)`.

Now, I have a Schedule field in the task creation form and it's a DateTime field. I would like to know how to send the task reminder mail at that exact date and time. Do I have to calculate the days and hours from Time.now and covert them to minutes using a model method and pass in the value or is there an easier way to get this done?

Comment: Why not just `perform_at` instead of `perform_in` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a couple of different ideas. Finally, I got it to work by converting the difference between Time.now and the scheduled time in minutes.